# Caesars Cipher, this is a freeCodeCamp coding challenge

Tags: javascript

This is an encoder and decoder function, which takes an encoded value and returns the decoded value and it is called ROT13 Cipher where the values of the letters are shifted by 13 places. Thus 'A' ↔ 'N', 'B' ↔ 'O' and so on. I don't know why my code isn't working, can anyone please explain?
Here is my code below:

```
function rot13(str) {
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
   let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
   if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90){
     let vary = charCode + 13;
     if (vary > 90){
       let newVary = vary - 90 - 1 + 65;
       str.replace(String.fromCharCode(charCode), String.fromCharCode(newVary));
     } else {
       str.replace(String.fromCharCode(charCode), String.fromCharCode(vary));
     };
   };
 };
 return str;
}; console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Comment: `str.replace(...)` doesn't modify `str`; it returns a new string that you need to assign and/or return.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` does not replace directly the variable. It returns the new string. Instead, use:

```js
str = str.replace(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues

- `replace` does not change the existing string, it returns the modified one
- replace will also only change the first occurrence, unless you use a regular expression with the global flag set
- your algorithm will modify already "decoded" chars in subsequent iterations in the loop

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let decoded = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
      let vary = charCode + 13;
      if (vary > 90) {
        let newVary = vary - 90 - 1 + 65;
        decoded += String.fromCharCode(newVary)
      } else {
        decoded += String.fromCharCode(vary)
      };
    } else {
      decoded += String.fromCharCode(charCode)
    }
  };
  return decoded;
};
console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```